# number of subsequences whose sum is divisible by k

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I just did a coding challenge for a company and was unable to solve this problem. Problem statement goes like:

**Given an array of integers, find the number of subsequences in the array whose sum is divisible by k, where k is some positive integer.**

For example, for `[4, 1, 3, 2]` and `k = 3`, the solution is 5. `[[3], [1, 2], [4,3,2], [4,2], [1,3,2]]` are the subsequences whose sum is divisible by `k`, i.e. `current_sum + nums[i] % k == 0`, where `nums[i]` is the current element in the array.

I tried to solve this recursively, however, I was unable to pass any test cases. My recursive code followed something like this:

```
def kSum(nums, k):
    def kSum(cur_sum, i):
        if i == len(nums): return 0
        sol = 1 if (cur_sum + nums[i]) % k == 0 else 0
        return sol + kSum(cur_sum, i+1) + kSum(cur_sum + nums[i], i+1)
    return kSum(0, 0)
```

What is wrong with this recursive approach, and how can I correct it? I'm not interested in an iterative solution, I just want to know why this recursive solution is wrong and how I can correct it.

Comment: @W-B I thought code review is more for coding style, best practices and stuff like that. This is a code that doesn't work, and OP is asking why, I thought that's what we help with here at SO?

Comment: Your example lists [3] and [1,2], but what about [4,3,2], [4,2], and [1,3,2]? I suspect there's some core aspect of the original question not captured here, because your code gives the correct answer for the example (5) and seems like it should work in general.

Comment: Is it possible that they wanted the number of *contiguous* non-empty subsequences with sums divisible by *k*? Then 2 would be the correct answer for your example: [3] and [1,3,2] are the only such subsequences.

Comment: Sorry, I realize that I clarified incorrectly. The answer should ALSO include [4,3,2], [4,2], and [1,3,2]. Did not realize I wrote the solution to that test case incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that is not the case test? For example:

```
[4, 1, 3, 2], k = 3
```

has

```
4+2 = 6, 1+2=3, 3, 1+2+3=6, 4+2+3 = 9
```

So, your function is right (it gives me 5) and I don't see a major problem with your function.

Comment: yea i retracted my comment almost immediately after reviewing the question, sorry. I agree with your hand calculation results.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for the initial confusion, I have updated my question accordingly to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript reproduction of what you wrote with some console logs to help explain its behavior.

```js
function kSum(nums, k) {
  let recursive_depth = 1;
  function _kSum(cur_sum, i) {
    recursive_depth++;
    
    if (i == nums.length) {
      recursive_depth--;
      return 0;
    }
    let sol = 0;
    if (((cur_sum + nums[i]) % k) === 0) {
      sol = 1;
      console.log(`Found valid sequence ending with ${nums[i]} with sum = ${cur_sum + nums[i]} with partial sum ${cur_sum} at depth ${recursive_depth}`);
    }
    const _kSum1 = _kSum(cur_sum, i+1);
    const _kSum2 = _kSum(cur_sum + nums[i], i+1);
    const res = sol + _kSum1 + _kSum2;
    
    recursive_depth--;
    return res; 
  }
  return _kSum(0, 0);
}

let arr = [4, 1, 3, 2], k = 3;
console.log(kSum(arr, k));
```

I think this code actually gets the right answer. I'm not fluent in Python, but I might have inadvertently fixed a bug in your code though by adding parenthesis around `(cur_sum + nums[i]) % k`

Comment: We want to return scalar value though, no? We want number of sums divisible by k.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your solution is correct. It reaches the answer by trying all subsequences, which has `2^n` complexity. We could formulate it recursively in an `O(n*k)` search space, although it could be more efficient to table. Let `f(A, k, i, r)` represent how many subsequences leave remainder `r` when their sum is divided by `k`, using elements up to `A[i]`. Then:

```js
function f(A, k, i=A.length-1, r=0){
  // A[i] leaves remainder r
  // when divided by k
  const c = A[i] % k == r ? 1 : 0;

  if (i == 0)
    return c;
  
  return c +  
    // All previous subsequences 
    // who's sum leaves remainder r
    // when divided by k
    f(A, k, i - 1, r) +

    // All previous subsequences who's
    // sum when combined with A[i]
    // leaves remainder r when
    // divided by k
    f(A, k, i - 1, (k + r - A[i]%k) % k);
}

console.log(f([1,2,1], 3));
console.log(f([2,3,5,8], 5));
console.log(f([4,1,3,2], 3));
console.log(f([3,3,3], 3));
```